# Google Contacts Addresses switched street name and house number

Tags: google-contacts, gmail-contacts

In my google contacts, for all contacts that have addresses attached, the street name and house number have switched places.

So, instead of

> Example street 123

Which is how I entered the information, it was switched to

> 123 Example street

This might be a localization issue: In Germany (where I live) it is customary to put the house number after the street name, while in other countries it is customary to do it the other way around.

The default language for my google account is german, so this should not be the cause of the issue.

Is there any way to remedy this situation? If I manually edit the address, it ends up correctly—only for how long? Also, this would be a lot of work.

Comment: Since it sounds like this just started happening, I would reference Google's changelog for Google Contacts, as a formatting change like this likely wouldn't have been done on a whim by Google and would therefore be documented, or it's a mistake/bug and a bug report would need to be filed to make them aware of the issue.

Comment: At some point this happened to me as well, I have no idea why. Probably it was Google, but I also thought a third party app perhaps could have done it, I am very baffled.

Answer (score 2):

How many words (Max) your address line?

Currently, manually, if you can export all your contact into a spreadsheet. You will need to edit only the address column. If there are many addresses rows, you can tweak with formula.

After you complete the changes, you need to delete all the contacts from contacts.google.com and then import the file again.

Comment: Excellent idea.  I personally would attempt this with only one contact, wait a day or so if it imports correctly, then do the rest if it remains unchanged by Google Contacts.  Since it sounds like this just started happening by the OP, it's possible a re-import will result in the same - a great idea nonetheless.

Comment: Not a good idea. This is happening all the time since many years ago. I tried to contact google several times with no response. I have a script to fixing it automatically. But recently this is happening very frequently. Can not use addresses any more.